# Executing a procedure in Oracle 11g Express showing error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle with System as username. I have created a database named STUDY.
I have a table named LIB created with following SQL statement:

```
create table lib(
book varchar(20)
);
```

I have created a procedure name SUB with following SQL statements:

```
create or replace procedure SUB( sbook IN VARCHAR)
as
begin
insert into LIB values(sbook);
end;
/
```

I have also granted EXECUTE privilege with following SQL statement:

```
grant EXECUTE on SUB to system;
```

Now when I try to execute the SUB procedure with following SQL statement:

```
execute STUDY.SUB ('mybook');
```

I get the following error:

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Execute it as

```
begin
execute STUDY.SUB ('mybook');
end;
```

Comment: `execute` is an SQL*Plus and SQL Develper command that wraps a simple `begin ... end` around a single command, for convenience. It is not something you can call from inside a PL/SQL BLOCK. Not to be confused with ``execute immediate` for dynamic SQL...

Answer (score 0):

Firsly, do the absolute minimum as the `SYSTEM` account, and don't create objects under that schema (or any other built-in schemas, especially `SYS`).

If you ran all of those commands as `SYSTEM` then you created the `SUB` procedure under the `SYSTEM` schema, not the `STUDY` schema. You haven't created a `STUDY` *database*, that isn't how Oralce does things; you've created a *schema* by creating a user. (At least, I think that's what you've done, it's possible you're doing all of this within a database called `STUDY`, but I doubt it).

What you probably should have done is:

```
connect study/password
create table lib ( ... );
create or replace peocedure ( ... );
/
execute sub( ... );
```

If you're experimenting with grants then you need to create a second user, say `USER2`, and still as `STUDY`:

```
grant execute on sub to user2;
```

Then connect as the second user and exectute the procedure:

```
connect user2/password
execute study.sub ( ... );
```

It would be unusual to even grant privs to `SYSTEM`, usually that would only be done for normal users and roles.